# Can PostgreSQL select from an array returned by a function?

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

This query fails:

```
SELECT xpath('/my/xpath/expr', my_xml)[1] FROM my_table

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "["
```

But this one works:

```
SELECT x[1] FROM
    (SELECT xpath('/my/xpath/expr', my_xml) as x FROM my_table) as ss
```

My xpath expression always returns only a single value, but the Postgres xpath function returns an array.  I want to select the first value in the array.  While the subselect works, it's pretty ugly.

Why doesn't the first query work, and is there a cleaner way to do this than the second query?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT (xpath('/my/xpath/expr', my_xml))[1] FROM my_table;
```

Comment: That was a remarkably simply solution!  I guess when in doubt, use more parentheses.